# The sprite kit nodes can't actually be removed from parent

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have made 30 bullets with a mutableArray to reuse them.

```
for var i = 0; i < 30; i++ {
    var bulletTmp = SharedAtlas.getInstance().getSpriteNode(SKSpriteType.bullet)

    bulletTmp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bulletTmp.size)
    bulletTmp.physicsBody.dynamic = true
    bulletTmp.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bulletCategory
    bulletTmp.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory
    bulletTmp.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory

    moveBulletToTop = SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.height, duration: NSTimeInterval((self.frame.height - plane.position.y) / 400.0))

    bulletGroup.addObject(bulletTmp)
}
```

The bullets is their parent SKNode

```
bullets.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5), (SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.05),SKAction.runBlock({
    var newBullet:MGSpriteNode!

    if self.bulletIndex < 29{
        self.bulletIndex++
    }else{
        self.bulletIndex = 0
    }
    newBullet = self.bulletGroup.objectAtIndex(self.bulletIndex) as MGSpriteNode

    newBullet.removeAllActions()
    newBullet.removeFromParent()
    print(self.childNodeWithName("bullets").children.count)//max value keeps 30

    newBullet.runAction(self.moveBulletToTop)

    newBullet.position = self.plane.position
    newBullet.position.y += self.plane.size.height * 0.5

    self.childNodeWithName("bullets").addChild(newBullet)

})])))]))
```

The question is: I have remove from parent after the bullet moves for a while. But the nodes number on the screen is keep increasing. The children of bullets always be 30 . If I move all of the bullets, everything will be OK. But where are the nodes? Had they actually been removed?

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger ?

Comment: @prototypical I don't know which node they belongs to

Comment: You could put a breakpoint on every addChild or removeChild line in your code and verify whenever something is being added/removed. Stepping through the code allows you to see if what you "expect" is really happening. The nodes number on the screen is not solely for your bullets node. Right ? Also, from your code, we have no idea how many times this method gets called and where `bulletIndex' is defined etc etc etc. I think you'd benefit from stepping through your code and verifying what you think is happening, is truly happening.

Comment: @prototypical Appreciated for your help, but I had do as what you say before I post the question. I use the bulletIndex to reuse the bullets from 0 to 29. Each breakpoint output the right result. The number of nodes on the screen looks like increasing with the bullet creating, while bullets's children number keep in 30.

Comment: If everything was correct at your breakpoints, there'd be no problem. Sorry, this question amounts to "debug my code", and not enough code to do it properly.